# How to set foreign key property with NOT NULL in multiple relationships

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I have following two entities

```
public class User
{
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; } // PK

        // for many-to-many relation with Booking.Members
        public virtual ICollection<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }
}

public class Booking
{
        public Booking()
        {
            Members = new List<User>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; } // PK

        [ForeignKey("UserByCreated")]
        public int UserByCreatedId { get; set; } // FK
        public virtual User UserByCreated { get; set; } 

        // for many-to-many relation with User.Bookings
        public virtual ICollection<User> Members { get; set; }

}
```

As shown above, User and Booking have two different relationships, one is many-to-many and the other is foreign key relationship.

What I want to do is having a UserByCreatedId foreign key column with NOT NULL condition in Bookings table.

However, it seems not possible due to another relationship with User. 
Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Fluent API to configure the relationships because EF fails to identify the relationship ends when there are multiple relationships between two entities.

**Edit**

The `UserByCreated` relationship needs to be changed to optional to avoid the multiple delete paths problem.

```
public class Booking
{
        public Booking()
        {
            Members = new List<User>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; } // PK

        [ForeignKey("UserByCreated")]
        public int? UserByCreatedId { get; set; } // FK

        public virtual User UserByCreated { get; set; } 

        public virtual ICollection<User> Members { get; set; }    
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(u => u.Bookings)
         .WithMany(b => b.Members);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Booking>().HasOptional(u => u.UserByCreated)
         .WithMany()
         .HasForeignKey(b => b.UserByCreatedId)
         .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

Comment: UserByCreated and UserByCreatedId properties are in Booking entity not User entity, so "modelBuilder.Entity<Booking>().HasRequired(b => b.UserByCreated).WithMany().HasForeignKey(b=>b.UserByCreatedId); " might by correct. BTW, even though I did as your advice I got following exception "Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_BookingUsers_Users_UserId' on table 'BookingUsers' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.\r\nCould not create constraint. See previous errors."

Comment: For more information, I also added fluent api for many-to-many relationship as follow "modelBuilder.Entity<Booking>()
                        .HasMany(b => b.Members)
                        .WithMany(u => u.Bookings)
                        .Map( m =>
                        {
                            m.ToTable("BookingUsers");
                            m.MapLeftKey("BookingId");
                            m.MapRightKey("UserId");
                        });

Comment: @Ray Edited my answer. You will have to add `WillCascadeOnDelete(false)` to the one to may relationship

Comment: Eranga, What I was going to do was set UserByCreateId wit NOT NULL, if I add WillCascadeOnDelete(false), it is NULLABLE, that is not I want

Comment: @Ray SQL Server will not allow you to create a FK if you don't make it null(the multiple delete paths issue). Validate the condition in your application layer to avoid setting it to null.

Comment: can you elaborate more about multiple delete paths issue?

Comment: @Ray When a `User` is deleted `Booking` can be deleted directly via `UserByCreatedId` or though `User` -> `BookingUsers` -> `Booking`.